# How color single page within margin?

Tags: overleaf, backgrounds, page

How do I color a page within the margin and still being able to write text on the page? I would like to make something like this.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can e.g. use eso-pic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*
  {\AtTextLowerLeft{\textcolor{green!50!white}{\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using OpTeX, you can use `\pgbackground` tokens register and create `\hrule` with desired dimensions shifted by `\voffset` and `\hoffset`:

```
\colordef\LiGreen{.2\Green+.03\Black}

\newbox\bgbox
\setbox\bgbox=\vbox{\LiGreen\hrule height\dimexpr\vsize+3pt width\hsize}
\pgbackground={\kern\voffset \moveright\hoffset\copy\bgbox}

\lorem[1-10]

\bye
```